# Programmatically Selecting a TabBarController View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In order to get my custom menu up and running, I've ended up using a `UITabBarController` and need to change the view displayed programmatically, vs the standard tabbed menu on screen.

Everything is working as expected except on thing. I am attempting to use:

```
[self setSelectedIndex:index];
```

This code is inside my `UITabBarController` subclass in a custom delegate method. (This is so I can programmatically adjust the view when interacting with my menu). However, while this code is called, it doesn't do anything?

Does it HAVE to be called from one of the tabbed views? I was hoping to run it from inside the TabBarController to avoid repeating the code in each tabbed sub controller.

**UPDATE:**

Just found that using `[self setSelectedIndex:index];` works fine in `viewDidLoad`. But when it is called inside the delegate method, it doesn't change view. It is using the right index number and getting called, but not doing anything from that method.

Also, it seems the tab controller is a different object when I log  `self` in `viewDidLoad` vs my delegate method. So why would I be loosing the reference to the original controller?

It's just a UITabBarController in a container in another view controller.

**Delegate Code:**

@Interface

```
@protocol SLMenuDelegate <NSObject>

@required -(void)menuDidChangeViewToIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SLMenuDelegate>menuDelegate;
```

@Implementation

```
@synthesize menuDelegate;

self.menuDelegate = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarViewController"];

[menuDelegate menuDidChangeViewToIndex:[self.menuItemButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
```

UITabBarController

```
-(void)menuDidChangeViewToIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [self setSelectedIndex:index];
}
```

Setting breakpoints and running NSLogs and there is no question that the method gets called and all code runs.

Comment: No, you can definitely call the setSelectedIndex method from your Ccustom TabBarCviewController file. Yours is most likely not working because because you have not linked your custom TabBarViewcontroller to your interface builder's TabBarViewController. so add this line `NSLog(@"selected index: %i",[self selectedIndex]);` to your viewDidLoad method in your custom TabBarViewController.m file and please tell me what is printed

Comment: Here is what I got from the console: `selected index: 2147483647`. Interesting. I have set the custom class of the UITabBarController in my storyboard, if thats what you mean?

Comment: Just found that using `[self setSelectedIndex:index];` works fine in `viewDidLoad`. But when it is called inside the delegate method, it doesn't change view. It is using the right index number and getting called, but not doing anything from that method.

Comment: Check my original question, found out some interesting extra info!

Comment: paste your delegate method code, also have an nslog statement in your delegate method and make sure that is getting called :)

Comment: Updated the question with that info. It all gets called and runs.

Comment: Do you mind if i test your basic project on my end to see whats going on? I can have a closer look at it if you like :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44913/discussion-between-pavan-and-josh-kahane)

Comment: Thanks @Pavan but I managed to find a solution! With your help, digging around, I worked out a resolution and I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a solution to the exact issue, but I found an equally good way of resolving my issue simply.

I stopped using a delegate to send my button tap message and change the view. Instead I did the following:

```
SLTabBarViewController *tabBar = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBar setSelectedIndex:[self.menuItemButtons indexOfObject:sender]];
```

This gets the embedded tab bar controller and I simply directly change the view from the original view controller from which the button tap comes from.

It may not be an intelligent solution, but its a simple and functional one which doesn't create any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using delayed performance:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self setSelectedIndex:index];
 });
```